# Why does a range with invalid arguments sometimes not cause an argument error?

Tags: ruby, exception, range, ruby-1.9.3, argument-error

The following code causes an argument error:

```
n = 15
(n % 4 == 0)..(n % 3 == 0)
# => bad value for range (ArgumentError)
```

which I think is because it evaluates to:

```
false..true
```

and different types of classes are used in range: `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`. However, the following code does not raise an error. Why is that? Does `Enumerable#collect` catch it?

```
(11..20).collect { |i| (i % 4 == 0)..(i % 3 == 0) ? i : nil }
# => no error
```

**Added later:**  If **fcn** returns 15, then only first half of range is evaluated

```
def fcn(x)
  puts x
  15
end

if  (fcn(1) % 4 == 0)..(fcn(2) % 3 == 0); end
# => 1
```

but if we change return value to 16 then input will be

```
# => 1
# => 2
```

It's strange, because in this case expression evaluates to

```
true..false
```

And such kind of range is invalid according to **sawa**'s answer below.

Then in first case (with ***def***'s return value 15) we have only partial range with no ending part?  It's so strange :)

Comment: Quite interesting. It seems "(expression1)..(expression2) ? a : b" only calculate expression1 to determine its value. You can only "eval someRange ? a : b" to test this. Looks like nothing to do with Enumeralbe#collect.

Comment: The question can be simplified: why `(true..false); 1` works but `x = (true..false); 1` does not? btw, this does not happen with Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: **halfelf**, I rewrite the code without using conditional operator, but simple if/then and still no exception (11..20).collect do |i|
  if (i % 4 == 0)..(i % 3 == 0) then i
  else nil
  end
end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby `if start..finish` is a flip-flop, a special syntax for writing fast and obscure scripts. It is usually used in loops:

```
while input = gets
  puts "Processing #{input.inspect}" if input =~ /start/ .. input =~ /end/
end
```

When the first condition is true, the whole condition is considered true on every consecutive execution until the second condition evaluates to true. You can play with the above script to get the idea. Here is my input & output:

```
foo
start
Processing "start\n"
foo
Processing "foo\n"
bar
Processing "bar\n"
end
Processing "end\n"
foo
bar
start
Processing "start\n"
```

Note that if the condition is not started Ruby doesn't evaluate the finishing condition because this is useless to do so.

Although it does not make much sense to use this outside of loops, Ruby is not restricting that.

```
>> if nil..raise; :nothing_gonna_happen; end
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note the following valid and invalid literals:

```
true..true # => valid
false..false # => valid
true..false # => invalid
false..true # => invalid
```

So the question reduces to why the expressions that evaluate to `false..true` and `true..false` become valid when embedded in a loop condition. According to [documentation](http://doc.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.9.2/doc/spec=2foperator.html#range_cond), a range literal in loop condition does not actually create a range. It rather has a special meaning akin to sed and awk. That is, the truth of the start of a range initiates the loop and truth of the end of the range terminates it. Some examples found [here](http://randomtype.ca/2011/range-conditions-in-ruby/).

Comment: it's not related to being a loop condition, see my comment to the question.